# Python netaddr throwing error when hitting empty csv cell

Tags: python, csv

I have a static CSV document with the following headers

```
City    State   Zip Latitude    Longitude   Subnet  Wired1  Wired2  Wireless1   Wireless2   Domain  Name    NAT_DHCP    NAT_Wireless
```

When searching for an IP, I look between the two wireless headers as well as the wired headers.

```
if (addr >= wired1 and addr <= wired2) or (addr >= wireless1 and addr <= wireless2):
print all header fields.
```

Now some entries have missing wireless ranges and/or missing wired ranges. I get the following error:

```
netaddr.core.AddrFormatError: failed to detect a valid IP address from ''
```

more specifically on the wireless header:

```
  File "script.py", line 175, in myfile
wireless1 = (int(IPAddress(row['Wireless1'])))
```

Now, I'm using Dictreader and from the documentation, isn't it supposed to skip empty lines? Is there another method that I could use to skip lines?

```
with open('csvfiles/myfile.csv', 'rb') as incsv:
    reader = csv.DictReader(incsv, delimiter=',')
```

here's my variables if curious:

```
addr = (int(IPAddress(ip)))
wired1 = (int(IPAddress(row['Wired1'])))
wired2 = (int(IPAddress(row['Wired2'])))
wireless1 = (int(IPAddress(row['Wireless1'])))
wireless2 = (int(IPAddress(row['Wireless2'])))
```

Example csv lines:

```
Wired1      Wired2          Wireless1     Wireless2
10.65.0.0   10.65.239.255   10.65.240.1   10.65.255.254
10.38.0.0   10.38.239.255       
10.34.0.0   10.34.239.255   10.34.240.1   10.34.255.254
10.83.0.0   10.83.239.255
```

Comment: Can you add few rows of the csv file you are reading?

Comment: added ranges, but I kept all the other info out for security reasons.

Comment: Add dummy values where you cannot show actual value, it will be easy to reproduce your problem and help you.

Comment: Hmm, I could fill all the empty rows with a range of 1.1.1.1 - 1.1.1.2, then they'd never fire, but atleast theyd skip over.

Comment: but I was looking for a quick way to go through the csv rather than dummy inputs, but this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html), you can manipulate your `csv` file lot better.

`import pandas as pd`

[`df = pd.read_csv('your_file.csv')`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

```
#See how does your data looks like in pandas
print df

      Wired1         Wired2    Wireless1      Wireless2
0  10.65.0.0  10.65.239.255  10.65.240.1  10.65.255.254
1  10.38.0.0  10.38.239.255          NaN            NaN
2  10.34.0.0  10.34.239.255  10.34.240.1  10.34.255.254
3  10.83.0.0  10.83.239.255          NaN            NaN

#Select only the rows where 'Wireless1' is not null
df[pd.notnull(df['Wireless1'])]
      Wired1         Wired2    Wireless1      Wireless2
 0  10.65.0.0  10.65.239.255  10.65.240.1  10.65.255.254
 2  10.34.0.0  10.34.239.255  10.34.240.1  10.34.255.254

#Select only 'Wireless' clolumn where it is not null
df[pd.notnull(df['Wireless1'])]['Wireless1']
0    10.65.240.1
2    10.34.240.1
Name: Wireless1, dtype: object
```

Likewise you can do many more manipulations using pandas. Thus you can avoid null values being passed to `netaddr`.